# jQueryMobile add click event to a button instead of changing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<p><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" onclick="doSomething(); return false">VERIFY</a></p>
```

I am using the above code which is a jQM button with the onClick() set. The onclick is called and doSomething() is executed but after that, jQM shows the "error loading page" message.

How can I supress the error? In this case I want the jQM button but don't want it to change page.

Thanks

Comment: why not remove the href?

Comment: So glad I finally stumbled upon this question, I kept getting "synchronous xml error" which totally put me on the wrong track...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery I would recommend to use jQuery to wire up your events as well.  With that being said using `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` should stop jQuery mobile from performing the default action on the `<a/>`.

```
$("#verify").click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do important stuff....
});
```

**Update**

The better way to use your existing markup would be to simply add `rel="external"` to your `<a/>`  And your `onclick` should behave correctly.

```
<p>
  <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" onclick="doSomething(); return false" rel="external">VERIFY</a>
</p>
```

This will work since jQuery Mobile will treat the link as a normal `<a/>` tag and return false will simply stop the default action.

Comment: That rel="external" ... is worth 6 jQM-n00b-hours

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem is that you have multiple actions on your button and are using a anchor tag. When clicking the button you're invoking the page to transition to index.html and a onClick event.

```
<a 
    href="index.html"                       <-- go to index.html
    data-role="button" 
    data-icon="arrow-r" 
    data-iconpos="right" 
    data-theme="a" 
    onclick="doSomething(); return false">  <-- Click event
VERIFY
</a>
```

Might try (might need to remove/add some other attributes)

```
<input
    type="button"
    name="verify"
    id="verify"
    data-icon="arrow-r" 
    data-iconpos="right" 
    data-theme="a" 
    value="VERIFY" />
```

and now add a click event

```
$('#verify').click(function() {
    alert('Button has been clicked');
});
```

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vRr82/2/

Comment: This isn't working. I think it's because jQM hides the <input> button and shows an styled <a> tag instead, so you're clicking the <a> not the <input> (which has the click event).

Comment: This is the correct solution. Also just removing the href should also work.

Comment: I am using cefsharp browser in my form application. I tried your code which is working fine can you please tell how can I load another HTML page from project resources on this button click **OR** how can I call a c# method on this button click. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be append `data-ajax="false"` inside anchor tag..
because in jQuery mobile the page transition is done by AJAX, and for page transition
it must be false..

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery live Function. That is prety much useful for me

Comment: Besides that I don't see how that answers the question as of jQuery 1.7 `live()` has been [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).