# How do I create a click-and-hold button on a webpage for mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I have a button on a page alongside some JS which gives it click-and-hold behaviour. Holding down the mouse button increases some value on the page over time. A demo of what I mean is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ianb/kS8Hf/

The problem is that when I view this page on my mobile (Android 2.3.5) the button behaviour is overridden my the browser. If I hold down the button, I get a prompt asking me if I want to save the button image.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour in the browser, or otherwise implement this button behaviour on a page intended for mobile?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5676504/348841

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried some element with a background instead of image? Afaik, when u use *div* with a background browser should not popup a promt to save this image.

Answer (score 1):

The button behaviors are managed by the phone/os manufacturers. For best webapp experience, you should try to avoid events like "hold down" and try to implement buttons for in-/decreasing the values. It's the same with sliders, there is no method for making a slider work on a touchscreen :)

regards
chris

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.click_and_hold').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    beginAdjust(10);
})
```

or you can try to `return false` on mousedown.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't fix it. It still prompts me to download the button image.