# Jquery Mobile Onclick event does not work before refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I Created some button with an onclick event that runs a function that alerts `"hi"`. The onclick event only works if I refresh the page.

Here is the function:

```
function testme(){
   alert("test");
}
```

And here is the onclick event:

```
<a href="#" id="someid" onClick="testme()">Button</a>
```

How can I make an onclick event work without having to refresh the page?

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676258/jquerymobile-add-click-event-to-a-button-instead-of-changing-page

Answer (score 1):

You could try not using a function if that is all you doing.

```
<a href="#" id="someid" onClick="alert('hi')">Button</a>
```

You could also try adding an click event in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#someid').click(function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hi')
 });
});
```

**edit 1**

From the question spookycoder suggested:

You could also use `rel="external"` on the a tag, this will allow it to perform normally on the jQuery Mobile pages.

Comment: yes , but i have some other functions with values and long functions . I Must use calling functions . what you seggested worked . but if I am calling a function instead of alert something it doesn't work .

What can I do about this ?
I need to call functions .
alerting is working fine but not calling functions .

Comment: Then I suggest you use the click event.

Comment: yes but it's not working when i am trying to call a function to do something

Comment: Are these buttons being added Dynamically?

Comment: what do you mean by "Dynamically" ? Sorry , my english is not the best.

Comment: Is the HTML being added via PHP or JavaScript? Or is this HTML already on the page?

Comment: Hmm well then try the `rel`. This should allow the onclick to work

Comment: hmm...im sorry then, there must me some other issue

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (especially on iPhone/iPad):

```
  <a href="javascript:testme()" id="someid">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround for this issue by changing the way I load my pages.
I put **target="_self"** into the href element so it don't load using the # system - this way the javascript loads with the initial page load while navigating from one page to a nother.

- I will put the below link on my index.html page that will navigate to my signup.html page.

`<a href="signup.html" target="_self" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Signup</a>`

NOTE: You will lose the 'fancy' jQuery Mobile page transition feature

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use :

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){ 

//Some Code

});
```

instead of :

```
$(document).ready(function (){

//Some Code

});
```