# Apply CSS class to clicked link from multiple links to same page, different sections

Tags: php, html, css

I have 3 links that all point to the same page but to different sections.

This is what the page sections look like, they are all similar- just read from different tables.

```
<h1>Networking</h1>
<?php 
  include 'inc/connect.php';
  $data = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM networking WHERE id = 1")or 
                       die(mysqli_error($link));           
  while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $data )) {
    echo nl2br($info['info']);}
?>  
</article>
```

This is the part of the menu file that has a link to 'Networking'.

```
if ($page == 'system') { 
 $output .="<li><a href='system.php#networking' class='active'>Networking</a></li>";}
 else{
   $output .="<li><a href='system.php#networking'>Networking</a> </li>";}
```

All the page section are in a page called system.php.
In the head of system.php I have this line

```
<?php $page = 'system'; ?>
```

This so I can apply the css class 'active' to the active link.

The way it is now, when I click on any 1 of my same page different section link the the class 'active' is applied to all 3 menu items.

Is there a way that I can apply the class to only the clicked link?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle so that we can see the coding for the active element. This is most likely due to them all having the same link even though the anchors are different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem, you could do something like this:

```
system.php?section=networking#networking
```

And do this at the top:

```
<?php $page = 'system'; $section=$_GET['section']; ?>
```

And then change your if statement to:

```
if ($page == 'system' AND $section == 'networking') {
```

Note: this is not the best solution, but uses your style, I hope this will help you!

Comment: Now I'm getting this error 'Undefined index: section' on this line'<?php $page = 'system'; $section=$_GET['section']; ?>'

Comment: Change it to if(isset($_GET['section'])) { $section=$_GET['section']; } else { $section = ""; }

Comment: Iknow have this at the top of my page <?php $page = 'system'; if(isset($_GET['section'])) { $section=$_GET['section']; } else { $section = ""; } ?> but it is applying the class to all 3 links!

Comment: The networking part is something that you have to change for each of the three links (so three different things for each of the links)

Comment: I got it! You said this is not the best solution, but as I'm a novice this seems quite good to me! So thank you very much for you help and patience on this issue.............

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
<?php $page =  parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_FRAGMENT ); ?>
```

But there is an additionnal issue you will need to have in mind. When you are already on the page and using a link to get on another section, the page won't reload.

If you want to update the active class in that case, you need something in javascript to do that.
Maybe that question can help you [jQueryMobile add click event to a button instead of changing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676258/jquerymobile-add-click-event-to-a-button-instead-of-changing-page)